# Manhwa with a blonde mother and a red-eyed, black-haired son & husband

Tags: story-identification, manga

The story is about a mother who gave birth to her child He has red eyes and black hair. He's close to nine or ten years old. The mother is a blonde. I think it's a postpartum depression. She was punishing him and going daily to dance parties. The boy grew up. The mother fell ill with a deadly disease, and she died, and her child did not care about her. She regretted, and she was returned in time to when he was young and took care of him.

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[The Flower Dances and the Wind Sings](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-flower-dances-and-the-wind-sings)***...?

> As Ersella lies on her deathbed, she has only one regret: never being a good mother to her son, Vicente. When fate sends her back three years, she gets a chance to make things right. While reflecting on her past as a young bride and reluctant mother, Ersella begins to untangle years’ worth of heartache. But as familial, marital, and even political issues enter the picture, she realizes there’s more to her second life than she thought. Will Ersella’s change of heart be too little, too late?
>
> [image: Promotional art for "The Flower Dances and the Wind Sings."]

Ersella, the blonde daughter of a marquess, marries a black-haired, blue-eyed duke at a young age and bears him a black-haired, blue-eyed son, Vicente. However, she doesn't spend much time with him, leaving him with his nanny so that she can attend parties with her friends. Her husband points out that her friends are childless, while she's a mother now whose priorities have changed, and even her friends at the parties express concern that she isn't with her son, but she doesn't listen.

Years later, she falls ill, and looking at Vicente from her deathbed, feels nothing but regret for neglecting him. She then dies and wakes up three years in the past, and the first thing she wants to do is see Vicente, who's currently sword training. Her maid worries that she's going to admonish him for something, and Vicente thinks the same thing, but instead, she offers him a few words of encouragement, something she'd apparently never done before.

You can read the full manhwa at [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/the-flower-dances-and-the-wind-sings/info).

Comment: Omggg I’m about to cry thank you ssoooooo much 

Comment: @wrixyc 1 - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.